# Fixed Left Column in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to ask, I have code like the following:

```js
// requires jquery library
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".main-table").clone(true).appendTo('#table-scroll').addClass('clone');
});
```

```css
.table-scroll {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.table-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.table-scroll table {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.table-scroll th,
.table-scroll td {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.table-scroll thead,
.table-scroll tfoot {
  background: #f9f9f9;
}

.clone {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.clone th,
.clone td {
  visibility: hidden
}

.clone td,
.clone th {
  border-color: transparent
}

.clone tbody th {
  visibility: visible;
  color: red;
}

.clone .fixed-side {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #eee;
  visibility: visible;
}

.clone thead,
.clone tfoot {
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table-scroll" class="table-scroll">
  <div class="table-wrap">
    <table class="main-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
          <th class="fixed-side">Left Column</th>
          <th scope="col">Header 2</th>
          <th scope="col">Header 3</th>
          <th scope="col">Header 4</th>
          <th scope="col">Header 5</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="alert('asd')">Test</a></th>
          <th class="fixed-side">Left Column</th>
          <td>Cell content<br> test
          </td>
          <td>Cell content longer</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side">Left Column</th>
          <th class="fixed-side">Left Column</th>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content longer</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>

      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

my problem is when the table that i created i scroll the alert function that i made can not be on tap / doesnt work. what I want to do is when I press the `test link` the alert that I create can work

Can anyone give me a solution what should I change so that the code I create works?

Comment: it's working fine here

Comment: try to scroll to right,it will not work,

Comment: because the elements all gets scroll but they are visible due to visibility property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are cloning element using the `clone` class where there is `pointer-events:none` which prevent you from clicking, so simply remove it and it will work.

Read more about [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

```js
// requires jquery library
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".main-table").clone(true).appendTo('#table-scroll').addClass('clone');
});
```

```css
.table-scroll {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.table-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.table-scroll table {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.table-scroll th,
.table-scroll td {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.table-scroll thead,
.table-scroll tfoot {
  background: #f9f9f9;
}

.clone {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.clone th,
.clone td {
  visibility: hidden
}

.clone td,
.clone th {
  border-color: transparent
}

.clone tbody th {
  visibility: visible;
  color: red;
}

.clone .fixed-side {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #eee;
  visibility: visible;
}

.clone thead,
.clone tfoot {
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table-scroll" class="table-scroll">
  <div class="table-wrap">
    <table class="main-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
          <th class="fixed-side">Left Column</th>
          <th scope="col">Header 2</th>
          <th scope="col">Header 3</th>
          <th scope="col">Header 4</th>
          <th scope="col">Header 5</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="alert('asd')">Test</a></th>
          <th class="fixed-side">Left Column</th>
          <td>Cell content<br> test
          </td>
          <td>Cell content longer</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side">Left Column</th>
          <th class="fixed-side">Left Column</th>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content longer</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>

      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sure its will work if i remove `pointer-events:none;`,  but how if i add link in scrollable content ? its will blocked and cant clicked

Comment: @AdamProjo no it won't  as i don't see nothing else blocking ;)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/AdamPSB/08hymnbh/ here my sample, how i can click the link ?

Comment: @AdamProjo yes i see, let me check

Comment: @AdamProjo here is an update https://jsfiddle.net/08hymnbh/1/ ... it was du to visibility so i used negative z-index instead

Comment: it does not work well, when I scroll until the link is not visible, it still can be clicked in the same place

Comment: @AdamProjo .. i thinnk it's difficult to do more, as the issue is coming from the way it's done ... Your code is cloning the table and make it on the top of the other. If i try to remove or hide some parts it's break :s

Comment: ah oke, maybe do u have other way make table like what i need ? with your own code,maybe ?

Comment: @AdamProjo yes sure ;) give me few minutes

Comment: @AdamProjo here is a try with your code https://jsfiddle.net/08hymnbh/3/ .. the idea is to add max-width to the element and make overflow:hidden with CSS. This will work on your case but i made the value fixed, you may elaborate the code to calcuate the needed height of the visible part ;)

Answer (score -1):

In CSS you have class:

```
.clone {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

Property

```
pointer-events:none;
```

disable mouse click event.
Delete this property and alert will work.

Comment: sure its will work, but i have other case like this,

https://jsfiddle.net/AdamPSB/08hymnbh/ if i delete the code my link will disabled for clicked

Comment: I can help you if you give me more information about general task .

Comment: If you deleted .code by this way:
jQuery('.clone').remove();

Comment: link of first table is enable for clicking